# Proper way to integrate Xamarin with jni

Tags: xamarin.android

I am moving my Android project to Xamarin. The Android project references an external library `libmyencoder.so.` Here is the signature for one of the functions that it exposes:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL encodeData (JNIEnv *, jclass, jlong,
    jobject, jint, jobject, jint);
```

On the Java side, the native method declaration is something as follows:

```
static native int encodeData(long handle,
    ByteBuffer input, int inputLen, ByteBuffer output, int maxOutputLen);
```

In Xamarin docs, I see a few examples of using dllimport. Based on this, I guess I could declare my C# method as follows:

```
[DllImport ("myencoder",EntryPoint="encodeData")]
public extern static void encodeData(long handle, ByteBuffer input,
   int inputLen, ByteBuffer output, int maxOutputLen);
```

Is this C# definition correct?

What is confusing is, although I have defined the entry point, I haven't specifically mentioned the native method's signature anywhere. This would be:

```
(JLjava/nio/ByteBuffer;ILjava/nio/ByteBuffer;I)I
```

Is Xamarin engine smart enough to deduce proper signature based on the method declaration?

Also, where would I copy `libmyencoder.so` to in my Xamarin project directory? Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, native calling from Xamarin is not documented well. After going through some source code at github and experimenting a bit, I discovered that 
Xamarin does not rely on Jni. You don't need to worry about sticking to Jni way of doing things. For example, the first parameter need not be `JNIEnv*` type. Also, you can simply pass pointers instead of jobjects as function parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Copy your "jniLibs" Java-Android contentent folder (including your .so files) to a "lib" folder under your Xamarin.Android project, example:

[image]

Set the "Build Action" of your .so files to "AndroidNativeLibrary".
[image]

The signatures of your methods should be like this:

```
[DllImport ("myencoder",EntryPoint="encodeData")]
public extern static void encodeData(IntPtr env, IntPtr class, IntPtr handle, IntPtr input, IntPtr inputLen, IntPtr output, IntPtr maxOutputLen);
```

You are using jint, jlong, jobject, so you can not directly use C# types, you have to use java types, for example in jint argument use, and you can not skip arguments like: JNIEnv *, jclass:

and You have to call your function with java arguments, for example:

```
Java.Nio.ByteBuffer inputSample = Java.Nio.ByteBuffer.Allocate(10);
Java.Nio.ByteBuffer outputSample = Java.Nio.ByteBuffer.Allocate(10);
System.IntPtr jClassSample = JNIEnv.FindClass(typeof(SomeClass));
Java.Lang.Long handleVal = new Java.Lang.Long(4);
Java.Lang.Integer inputLenVal = new Java.Lang.Integer(4);
Java.Lang.Integer maxOutputLenVal = new Java.Lang.Integer(4);

encodeData(JNIEnv.Handle, jClassSample, handleVal.Handle, inputSample.Handle, inputLenVal.Handle, outputSample.Handle, maxOutputLenVal.Handle);
```

For more detailed information check my answer here:

[Load .so file in Xamarin.Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47433520/load-so-file-in-xamarin-android/49743686#49743686)