# DllNotFoundException on Android even though library exists in the .apk

Tags: android, c++, unity-game-engine

so I'm pretty stuck at getting a native plugin in Unity on Android. On Ubuntu, it's working fine. So here's the situation:

1. In my C# script I import my function

```
[DllImport("Foo")]
public static extern int foo()
```

2. My C++ native foo.cpp file looks like this

```
extern "C" int foo() { return 1; }
```

3. For use in android I compiled this cpp file with the Compiler from Androids NDK

```
$NDK/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/armv7a-linux-androideabi21-clang++ -fPIC foo.cpp -o libFoo.so -shared
```

4. Placed it in my Unity Project in Assets/Plugins/Android/ (I've also tried putting it under *Assets/Plugins/Android/arm-v7a*  without success)
5. Selected *Exclude Platforms Android* for the original Linux library and *Include Platforms Android* on the libFoo.so built for Android in the Android subfolder
6. Platforms settings for the Android Plugin are set to CPU: ARMv7
7. Once I build and run on my Android device I get this error in my Android Logcat

> Error Unity DllNotFoundException: Foo

8. But when I open the .apk file the library exists in */lib/armeabi-v7a/libFoo.so*

I'd really appreciate it if somebody has a hint of what could have gone wrong since I've come to the end of my knowledge.

Comment: Is your unity executable targetting armeabi-v7a? If it is running a different architecture it wont be able to load the armeabi-v7a library

Comment: I don't have much experience with Xamarin but the error message `DllNotFoundException` sounds to that it expects a C#/.Net dll not a Linux .so file. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47433520/load-so-file-in-xamarin-android