# How to use java native method System.loadLibrary() in xamarin android?

Tags: android, xamarin

I need to load two libraries before starting my activity. I can use this method through the native java language in android studio, here is my java code that is working =>

```
    static {
    System.loadLibrary("gstreamer_android");
    System.loadLibrary("tutorial-1");
}
```

But in xamarin I can't find a way to load it... Does anyone know if there is something similar that I can use in xamarin? All I have for reference is this link [xamarin documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/java.lang.javasystem.loadlibrary?view=xamarin-android-sdk-12)

Comment: `JavaSystem.LoadLibrary()`

Comment: For future reference: any time you need xamarin equivalent of some java call, google `xamarin thatjavacall`. In your case, google `xamarin System.loadLibrary`. In the top few answers, you'll see xamarin's `JavaSystem.LoadLibrary`, as well as various related discussions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/java.lang.javasystem.loadlibrary?view=xamarin-android-sdk-12

JavaSystem.LoadLibrary(" [lib-name] ")

Or this may help
[Load .so file in Xamarin.Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47433520/load-so-file-in-xamarin-android)