# load .so file in xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, .so

need to load one .so file and call some native methods...
I have followed each single step

[Load .so file in Xamarin.Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47433520/load-so-file-in-xamarin-android)

not sure whether library is loading or not not...but there is not exception or error during loading

```
JavaSystem.LoadLibrary
```

but when I am calling methods its giving null reference exception,I am sure method names are correct in entry point

Comment: What's your `.so` file? How can we reproduce this problem? Could you please post the steps in detail so that we can try to reproduce this problem my side?

Comment: Thanks for reply,I will prepare a demo project and will upload